# Delete rows with date check

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

have table like this :

```
   user_id              Date                Status
    1000        2013-04-02 11:46:10.000       IN
    1001        2013-04-02 11:50:08.000       OUT
    1005        2013-04-02 11:46:24.000       IN
    1005        2013-04-02 12:50:04.000       OUT
    1005        2013-04-02 12:50:10.000       OUT
    1045        2013-04-02 14:46:05.000       IN
```

Want delete date where status IN or OUT is twice for one user. 
For example it must delete user_id 1005 where date is 2013-04-02 12:50:04.000  . I want leave only latest date

Comment: I suggest you add some row_id unique column to this table as primary key. Right now, the architecture you have seems ineficient to me. I am telling you this as someone, who has worked with such structure before.

Comment: Also, could you just try this query? This should work, and it will work on all platforms `DELETE FROM table WHERE date = (
SELECT t1.date FROM table t1 JOIN table t2 
ON (t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.Status = t2.Status)
WHERE t1.date < t2.date
)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) + `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT user_id, Date, Status,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, Status
                                 ORDER BY Date DESC)
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1
```

You can use `SELECT * FROM` to see what you're going to delete.

Here's a <kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f8f0d/5/2)</kbd> with your sample data.

Answer (score 1):

This answer will also work for older versions of mssql

```
delete t
from 
table t
where exists(select 1 from table 
             where t.user_id = user_id 
               and t.status = status
               and t.date < date)
```

The weakness of this answer is that if you have a senario with the same timestamp, the same user_id and the same date on 2 rows it will leave both rows intact

Comment: mmm it works with you without the id column but still not sure about what is the wrong when i compare dates in my case ( = )

Comment: @HadiHassan your datecomparison is down to the last millisecond. Your script will never delete any rows unless the dates are exactly the same which is unlikely to happen and not described in the test data in the question

Answer (score 0):

another approach is to delete the duplicated records in case you have a primary key for the table which i called " id ":

```
delete b
from TableName a
inner join TableName b on a.user_id=b.user_id
where a.Date=b.Date and a.Status=b.Status and a.id>b.id
```

Comment: basically you are inventing a new column that has no guarantee of corresponding with the dates in the right order. You are also joining on dates which is wrong

Comment: this id column can be auto generated column and can help in different scenarios especially once you try to use the abstract approach and generic ideas in your code, can you tell me what is wrong when i apply the join on date?

Comment: check my answer and you should get the idea